# Unable to show images on my web page fetching from FTP server in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image-uploading

I am unable to view images on my page, I am try to fetch images from FTP, But I am unable to view images. I have created local FTP and fetching images form local server and making images gallery and after using multiple checkbox transfer images in uploaded folder but this time I am unable to view my images on web-page, I am newbie in php.

```
    <?php
    $qt_folder_name = 'images'; // change this to a folder of your choice for images
            $qt_handle = opendir( dirname( realpath( __FILE__ ) ) . '/' . $qt_folder_name . '/' );

/* ========================================================================== */
/* ========================================================================== */
/*                                    FTP LOGIC                                   */


/* ========================================================================== */

            $qt_counter = 0;



            while( $qt_file = readdir( $qt_handle ) ) :

                if( $qt_file !== '.' && $qt_file !== '..' ) :

                    $qt_counter++;

                    $qt_file_path = $qt_folder_name . '/' . $qt_file;

                    ?>
<!-- ======================================================================= -->                    
          <?php
           $exp=  explode('!',$qt_file);
           ?>
<!-- ======================================================================= -->

                    <div class="qt-photo-gallery-item qt-image-no-<?php echo $qt_counter; ?>">
                        <a class="qt-photo-gallery-item-link" href="<?php echo $qt_file_path; ?>"title="<?php echo $exp[0]."\n".$exp[1]; ?><?php //echo $qt_file;?>">

                            <div class="qt-photo-gallery-item-image-wrapper">

                                <img src="<?php echo $qt_file_path; ?>" class="qt-photo-gallery-item-image" />
                                <p class="title_name"><?php echo $exp[0]."\n".$exp[1]; ?></p>
                            </div>


                        </a>
                    </div>

<!-- ======================================================================= -->

                    <?php

                    if( $qt_counter == 5 ) {
                        $qt_counter = 0;
                    }

                endif;

            endwhile;

/* ========================================================================== */

            ?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like in img src= you are  referencing path to image from file system not from your index directory of website, and that might cause problem.